# Assign value to a objective-c variable from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What I want to do is when user select a district from `UITableView` in Swift, I'm taking the district name and add `.png` to it and send the image name variable into Objective-C file and inside it I'm creating `UIImageView`.

This is my code inside my Objective-C .h file,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *mapImage;
```

This is how I assign value to it from Swift `UITableView` when user click on `UITableView` (`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`),

```
selectesState = namesArray[indexPath.row]
let temp :String = selectesState + ".png"
let instanceOfCustomObject: StateMapPinView = StateMapPinView()
instanceOfCustomObject.mapImage = temp
```

This is the Objective-C code I'm setting the image in .m file (`ViewDidLoad`),

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:_mapImage];
_myView = [[VIPhotoView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andImage:image];
_myView.autoresizingMask = (1 << 6) -1;

[self.view addSubview:_myView];
```

But it keeps returning null value.
Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the declaration of the property to:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *mapImage;
```

This will make sure that value is copied when assigned. In your case you use weak and therefore the value is deallocated at the end of the execution of the current scope.

Comment: I changed 'weak' to 'copy' as you suggest but still im getting null.

Comment: Can you please post the full code? Especially the part when you read from the `mapImage` property?

Comment: Where exactly do you have nil? In the line where you create image from `_mapImage`? Have you tried to use `self.mapImage`? Could you please post the interface and implementation parts of the class where you defined the `mapImage` property?

Comment: `StateMapPinView` is this the object that holds the table view? Could you please post the source code? And also how you initialise the table view.

It looks like instead of updating the object that holds the table view, you create another object and the the `mapImage` value of it. But this object doesn't have anything to do with the table view holder (I guess the viewDidLoad is called on an object where you initialise the table view).

Answer (score 0):

Makesure , you have the same 'instanceOfCustomObject' instance. 
If it is instantiated again, then you will get null for 'mapImage'.

Use the same instance of 'instanceOfCustomObject' and try in your Obj-c.

```
CustomObjectClass *instanceOfCustomObject = (CustomObjectClass *) 'same_instanceOfCustomObject';

[UIImage imageNamed: instanceOfCustomObject.mapImage];
```